# How to skip a document / page while searching in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

My current project contains four different projects and thousands of documents. Whenever I try to search a keyword it goes through all documents even if I knew that document or that group of documents in a folder is not what I am looking.

So is there a way to skip pages or folders while searching? Or is there any way to search only in one Folder of documents or selected document?

I searched in the net and couldn't find anything(may be I done the search wrong). Anyway looking forward for a solution.

I am using Visual-Studio 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Find And Replace window, there is a "..." button next to "Look In" dropdown. It allows you to specify folders to be included in search.

At least it is here in my Visual Studio Community 2017, and on VS2013 screenshots from the web. Hope it helps.